# Mysql query from a third table

Tags: mysql

I have a database with Orders, Order_content and Vendors table. I want to get the vendors in one order.

- Vendor(vid, company_name, phone_number)
- Order_content(ocid, product_name, vid)
- Order(oid, ocid, address, name, phone_number)

I want to get the company_name, address and phone_number from the Vendor table that are related to a specific order.

What I have tried.

```
SELECT vendor.company_name, vendor.address, vendor.phone_number FROM vendor WHERE vendor.vid = order_content.vid AND order_content.oid = order.oid;
```

Using JOIN

```
SELECT vendor.company_name, vendor.address, vendor.phone_number AS vendor_details
        FROM vendor
        INNER JOIN orders_content ON (vendor.vid = orders_content.vendor_id AND orders_content.oid = orders.oid) 
        WHERE vendor.id;
```

The SQL is wrong and not working, some help will be appreciated. I think I am supposed to use a JOIN, I tried but the SQL throws an error.
Thanks.

Comment: Please show your `JOIN` attempt.

Comment: Sure, let me update the question.

Comment: You're missing your 3rd table `orders`, add 1 `JOIN` per additional table.

Answer (score 0):

You are only joining `Vendor` and `Order_content`, but not `Order`, so you are missing some fields as a result:

```
SELECT vendor.company_name, vendor.address, vendor.phone_number AS vendor_details
        FROM vendor
        INNER JOIN orders_content ON (vendor.vid = orders_content.vendor_id AND orders_content.oid = orders.oid) 
        INNER JOIN order ON (orders_content.ocid = orders.ocid);
```

Note that I removed the `where` clause, since it did not make any sense.